# How to format money in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have float field that contains (for example): 1234.5678. I would like to display it like a 1 234.56 or 1 234,56. How can I do that?

I used `to_char()` function that gives me:

```
SELECT to_char(12345.5678,'99999999999999999D99');
-> 12345,57
```

but, when I have zero-value...

```
SELECT to_char(0,'99999999999999999D99');
-> ,00
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A zero inside:

```
SELECT to_char(0,'99999999999999990D99');
-- Second question from the comments: Howto make k-seperator
SELECT to_char (1234567890999999.8,'99 999 999 999 999 990D99');
```

Here is the [online-doku: functions (data-type conversion)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html). Maybe you like to download it.

Comment: Great! Do you know how to display it with a space? Like this: 1 234.56? Thanks anyway.

Comment: The simplest thing which could possibly work, is ...? Just tried it out, and - voila.

Answer (score 0):

Would also use trim to remove extra whitespace

SELECT trim(to_char(12345.67,'99999999999999999D99'));