# How to convert character variable such as 2000 to 2,000.00 format in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How to convert  character variable  to numeric format example is mentioned
2000 to 2,000.00 format in postgresql?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! As it stands, your question does not give very much information on your problem and also doesn't show that you've put in any effort towards solving it yourself. These are two things that you *must* show if you expect to receive help from others on this site. You should start by posting any code you've already tried, and telling us what didn't work with it, at which point we can help you address those problems.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format money in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419199/how-to-format-money-in-postgresql)

Comment: Check out the [Guide for Formatting Functions in PostreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the number with [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT to_char(2000::numeric, '999,999,999.00FM');

 to_char  
----------
 2,000.00
(1 row)
```

If you want to use the decimal and group separators defines by `lc_numeric`, use `D` and `G`.

Comment: OK thank you                                                     
 Can this be applied on column_name to convert entire column 


SELECT to_char(column_name::numeric, '999,999,999.00FM)

Comment: Yes, of course. The cast is unnecessary if the column is of a numeric data type.